# Timeouts when Uploading Cards to Facebook Messenger

Tags: botframework

Timeout when uploading HeroCard to the bot framework on messenger channel.

`Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 40.121.91.199:443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1007:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1030:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)`

When uploading seeing this error as well
`Error: Request to 'https://facebook.botframework.com/v3/conversations/1184220421
633853-1103485719738974/activities/mid.1470863624883%3Ae1dcd9f8a2c3d74b52' failed:` **[500] Internal Server Error**`

Comment: Can you share the contents of your card so I can debug?  (JSON preferably but code for generating card would be good to)

Comment: builder.CardImage.create(session, "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjM5OTQ1MTY5Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMjM3NzMxODE@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg")
                            .tap(builder.CardAction.showImage(session, "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjM5OTQ1MTY5Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMjM3NzMxODE@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg")),

Comment: Thanks.  Looking into it.

Comment: did someone found a Work around, im having the same problem...

Comment: we moved out of bot framework for now.